# Reading and outputting files in a directory in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have the following code, but when I run main.rb nothing shows up:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/reloader'

class Site < Sinatra::Base

  set :root, File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__) #converts path to absolute from here

  files = Dir["#{:root}files/"]

  get '/' do 
    files[1]
  end

  # start the server if ruby file executed directly
  run! if app_file == $0

end
```

The folder structure is as follows:

```
Site > lib > main.rb
Site > files > file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Comment: `"#{:root}files/"` is always going to evaluate to `"rootfiles/"`. Try using `files = Dir["#{settings.root}files/"]` instead.

Comment: @Matt Still turns up empty. Does it matter that its on windows?

Comment: Possibly. What does `File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__)` return?

Comment: In irb it returns the parent folder, so if I was in lib it returns site

Comment: Please quote it. Does it end in a slash? If not, then insert a slash between "#{settings.root}" and "files/".

Comment: Without a slash. Something weird is going on. I'll try in Ubuntu and let you know. Thanks for your help.